# Linear Algebra text with Matlab

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, matlab

We are in the process of revising our 2 quarter sequence on Linear Algebra and ODEs.  (The prerequisite is a 2 quarter sequence in differential and integral calculus.  This is a service course for hard science and engineering majors.)  For the Linear Algebra, I want to de-emphasize (but not eliminate) the 'by hand' calculation of reduced row echelon form, matrix inverses, characteristic polynomials, etc and introduce a Matlab component.  The course should include mention of iterative methods for computing eigenvalues/eigenvectors, as well as the singular value decomposition.  The students have no previous exposure to Matlab.

Can anyone recommend a Linear Algebra text that work well with Matlab?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=GmpV5YH4Mv8C) and [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=hmW0QgAACAAJ)?

Comment: @Peter: NCM is a bit wide, and focuses more on learning how to use MATLAB for numerical computing, and not much on the linear algebra guts...

Comment: @JM:  Thanks, the Williams book looks very promising.